# Poetry is being overwritten in docker and I can't see why - can you spot problem?

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

Here's the error after I try to run poetry directly (I gave up on PATH whilst troubleshooting) in a docker container:

`Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry": stat ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry: no such file or directory: unknown`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

# to run poetry directly as soon as it's installed
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

# INSTALL POETRY
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - 

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/
RUN ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry install --no-root

# copy files to Container
COPY ./. /app
CMD ["~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# Docker compose file for nginx and letsencrypt
version: "3.10"
services:
  fastapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: fastapi
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

What's strange is, poetry will actually build and install all those dependencies first, I watch them get instaled. Then when I try and use poetry at the cmd line, you the build errors out producing the error above. Suddently by that point in the build, the poetry installation is gone?

Comment: why do you use absolute path to poetry binary in some venv instead of simple `poetry` call? you have added ENV that allows you to run it directly. `poetry` will create virtual environment based on your `pyproject.toml`

Comment: Because I kept on getting "poetry not found" errors, even after running it directly in the install. When I would then come to use poetry in cmd, i would get an error that it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the JSON-array form of `CMD`.  This doesn't run a shell and doesn't to any sort of variable expansion.  In particular, `~` referring to the current user's home directory is a convenience offered by the shell, but since you're not running a shell here, the system instead interprets it as looking for a subdirectory of the current directory literally named `~`.

The shortest solution is to spell out the absolute path here

```
CMD ["/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
#     ^^^^^ explicitly spell out user's home directory
```

You try to set `$PATH` earlier, and another approach here could be to add the Poetry virtual environment to `$PATH`.

```bash
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin:$PATH"
#                      add ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

...

RUN poetry install --no-root
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

It looks like it might be possible to [install Poetry using `pip`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-manually) in which case you could install it outside a virtual environment, or [`poetry export`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#export) your project's dependencies to a `requirements.txt` file that you could more directly `RUN pip install -r` into the image's "system" Python.

Answer (score 0):

The `$HOME` directory is the working directory that you set.
So when you execute `RUN ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry`
the full path is `app/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry`
when it should be `root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry`.

Either define the full path or set the `root` dir as working directory